# Move View When Keyboard Appears - Only Upon Editing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uikeyboard

I have used the demonstration code Apple has in their docs here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7

To have my view move accordingly depending on which textField is being edited. It works great, my view moves as I expect, except for one thing.

My issue is, I can select a textField and it will only move the view up when I begin typing and not when I actually select the textField.

I am literally using identical code as in the docs (follow the link above). Quite frustrating, I can't see what would cause this. Thanks.

Comment: You SHould see my Edit.This Would Work as You needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is The Logic See.

1)You need a `Flag` Value Set `TRUE` initially in `ViewDidLoad` or `viewWillAPpear`.
suppose `isNeedToMove` is that Flag value.

you need to Implement these methods in Your Code,for using them don't forget to `Adopt` the protocol `UITextFieldDelegate`  in your `UIViewcontroller.h  class`.

**EDIT:Here I have Chnaged The Code AS you mentioned in yOur Comment You needed to move That UIView on just Touching the `TextFIeld`.See Here below Is The Logic With SOme Code.**

addTarget To the `TextField` in `ViewDiodiLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidload
{
 [touchyTextField addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(yourDesiredMethod)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
}

-(void)yourDesiredMethod
{
if(isNeedToMove)//this Flag Avoid The unnecessary move call.
{
 //here call the method which Move The UIview
 }
}


- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField
{

[textField resignFirstResponder];
//here call the method which move UIView to its actual position.
 isNeedToMove= TRUE;
 return YES;

}
```

I hope you may get Some idea .

Comment: @Josh Kahane do you still have that issue..?

Comment: Not at my computer currently, will try shortly and report back!

Comment: Ok, I've tried, no luck, same result. The view only moves up when typing and not when entering the text field.

Comment: @JoshKahane what are saying ..?it's bug turn by you.as i know you said  `I can select a textField and it will only move the view up when I begin typing and not when I actually select the textField`.I just give the answer according to it

Comment: @JoshKahane See My ANswer , I have Edited it And it would Work As you needed.

Comment: @JoshKahane Now Have You Got Any idea ?

Comment: Thanks for your continued help, but this isn't my issue trying to work with the existing Apple demo code. The code runs when tapped (before typing) but its that code which is rough (but thanks anyway).

Comment: @JoshKahane what are you saying this is not your issue so what is your issue?.I had edited my answer just after the your comment `Ok, I've tried, no luck, same result. The view only moves up when typing and not when entering the text field`.here you are creating little confusion.please be clear on your requirement...

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear. You understood my original question and I understand the approach you suggested and tried it, however it failed. This is where the question changes, thorugh this I have discovered that its actually `if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ` this if statement (you see in Apples docs) which isn't actually passing correctly. Now I need to work out why, but I can't.

Comment: @JoshKahane ok nops come on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19493/dissmissgroup11222

Answer (score 0):

I had this trouble too. In keyboardWasShown, the Apple documentation says:

```
 if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin)
```

I used:

```
if (activeField == myTextField)
```

Here's the long version of the answer: [moving content located under the keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345131/moving-content-located-under-the-keyboard)